# Google Sheets API insert column using batchUpdate InsertDimensionRequest gives empty response

Tags: google-sheets-api

Hi I am trying to insert a column in between existing columns using Google Sheets Api. I get a response without error as per below code but the column is not inserted in the sheets.

```
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ requests: [{
      insertDimension: {
        range: {
          sheetId: tabId,
          dimension: "COLUMNS",
          startIndex: index + 1,
          endIndex: index + 2,
        },
        inheritFromBefore: true,
      },
    }]
}),
}
try {
    const insertApi = await fetch(
      `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadSheetId}:batchUpdate`,
      options
    );
    const insertRes = await insertApi.json();
    console.log(insertRes);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Insert Column Error: ", error);
  }
```

this is my response from api

```
{spreadsheetId: '1b_H4613iP99BpKSatpKz79bEinCP9mplntf8Yf_P_zM', replies: Array(1)} replies: Array(1) 0: {} length: 1 [[Prototype]] : Array(0) spreadsheetId: "1b_H4613iP99BpKSatpKz79bEinCP9mplntf8Yf_P_zM" [[Prototype]]: Object}
```

My sheets has 5 columns now and I am trying to insert a new column at index 4.
any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: If `index 4` is column "E" with the start index of 0, I think that in your script, when all variables are valid values and `index` in your script is 3, a new column is inserted into column "E". So, I cannot understand `but the column is not inserted in the sheets`. I apologize for this. For example, your sheet ID is the sheet ID of your expected sheet?

Comment: @Tanaike I have five columns like this ["Name", "StartDate", "Flagged", "Tags", "Score"] and I want to insert a column "Test" between "Tags" and "Score". The value of index in my code is 4. Yes I checked the sheetId is correct

Comment: @Tanaike I changed my code startIndex: index + 1, endIndex: index + 2 to startIndex: index, endIndex: index + 1, and its working now. I got confused with the indexing. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code startIndex: index + 1, endIndex: index + 2 to startIndex: index, endIndex: index + 1, and its working now. I got confused with the indexing.